# Pass data to parent without click

Tags: reactjs, parent-child, parent

I just started to learn ReactJS and I need some help. I am trying to send data from child to parent component, and in child I have this button code

Here is my child

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";

class Locate extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      city: "",
      countryName: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://ipapi.co/json/")
      .then(response => {
        let data = response.data;
        this.setState({
          city: data.city,
          countryName: data.country_name
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p> Country Name: {this.state.countryName} </p>
        <button onClick={() => { this.props.updateCity(this.state.city)}}>My city</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Locate;
```

and here is my parent

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import Locate from "./location.js"


class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
  }

updateCity = (value) => {
   this.setState({ city: value });
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <Locate updateCity={this.updateCity} />

      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

all is working fine, but I need to pass this.state.city without button onClick function. How to do this?

Comment: If you dont want to pass it onclick. when do you want to pass it to the parent ?

Comment: @Muljayan is asking the right question; the original question is unanswerable without information about _when_ the data should be passed up.

Comment: You can do it in the callback function where you are setting the state in the child component maybe but why do you need to keep multiple `city` states like that? Do not try to sync the states like that, do have one state and update/use it. If you want to continue your logic, at least pass the `city` value to the parent and keep only the `country` state in the child. But, for React it is best to flow the data top to bottom, not the way you are doing here. You can reevaluate your logic according to that.

Comment: Also, if you update your parent's state like that it will trigger a rerender for your child component and this will cause an infinite loop unless you check some conditions. You can't do this because your both parent and child components depend on the same state. It is like the chicken/egg problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function in the component and call that at will when you need to in your application flow.

e.g.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";

class Locate extends React.Component {
...
  myFunction() {
   this.props.updateCity(this.state.city)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // example calling it on didMount 
    this.myFunction();
  }
....
}
```

If you need to share data between parent and child you could look into the `Context API` which may be useful for you